# ejs not including css

Tags: css, node.js, ejs

I've been trying to figure out why my ejs isn't including my css.

I've set up my header.ejs etc; but it isn't loading the css.

Please note that the header.ejs is indeed being included inside my index.ejs.
The only problem is that the stylesheets aren't being loaded.

I do realize that you need to tell ejs what you want to be loaded which I did. The directory is definitely correct. I used readdir to check whether the directory was outputting the contents of the folder which it did.

I'm wondering is it because it isn't under a static folder like public/css if that is the case how would I be able to change that?

server.js

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/client/vanity/public/assets/css'));
```

header.ejs

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/../assets/css/normalize.css/">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/../assets/css/skeleton.css/">
```

index.ejs

```
<% include views/header %>

  <!-- Primary Page Layout
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="one-half column" style="margin-top: 25%">
        <h4>Basic Page</h4>
        <p>basic template</a>.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<!-- End Document
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you inspect the source in the browser to see what it is loading from the static folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were to serve your static files as such:
 `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/client/vanity/public/assets/css'));`
then, when the files are referenced, the path starts with `/client/vanity/public/assets/css`.

This means that you would reference a css file as the following (suggesting your css files are in the /css folder):
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/normalize.css">`

Full path: `/client/vanity/public/assets/css` + `/normalize.css`.